# How To Expand Multiple Table <tr> On Single Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I'm trying to create a product comparison table that users can click a button to show/hide additional specification details.

I read you cannot do this with duplicate ids but I've had trouble trying to select by class.

The posted code is my closest attempt thus far.

```
function toggleTable()
{
 if( document.getElementById("hide").style.display=='none' ){
   document.getElementById("hide").style.display = 'table-row'; // set to table-row instead of an empty string
 }else{
   document.getElementById("hide").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```html
<h2>Table</h2>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Blank</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Blank</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="hide" style="display:none;">
        <td>Show/Hide</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="hide" style="display:none;">
        <td>Show/Hide</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="toggleTable()">Show/Hide ▼</button>
```

Comment: Showing what you tried to do when selecting by class would have helped this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using classes to identify the parts that will be manipulated - in your case for their display to be toggled - and I keep styles and code out of the html. No inline "onclick" handlers, and style is always in css.

I removed the `id` on the rows because it's not needed, and it's illegal to use the same id more than once.  I added an id to the button to make it easy to get it in javascript.
I've also done a little styling so it's easier to see the parts -- the table cells.

I'm using two classes
• `hideable` marks the rows that *can* be hidden or shown - things that are *hideable*
• `hidden` because I want to start with those rows already hidden

The code here gets the "toggle" button using the id I added to it, then adds an event listener to the button for the 'click' event, and I put the code to be run inline rather than making a separate function.

When the button is clicked it runs the code, which
• finds all things marked as `.hideable`
• toggles the class `hidden` on *each* thing found - so if it already has `.hidden` that is removed and the element becomes visible; if it *isn't* hidden the `.hidden` class gets added so the css selector `.hideable.hidden` sets the display to none.

```js
document.getElementById('toggle')
  ?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.hideable')
              .forEach(h => h.classList.toggle('hidden'));
  });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

th, td {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.hideable {
  display: default;
}

.hideable.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">Show/Hide ▼</button>
<h2>Table</h2>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Blank</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Blank</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hideable hidden">
        <td>Show/Hide</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hideable hidden">
        <td>Show/Hide</td>
        <td>Info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always try and avoid manupulating style directly in jacvascript and leave it to CSS classes to handle the actual style. Then it comes down to just toggling the styles with JavaScript.

This is very close to [Stephens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77370860/4665), with what I believe is a simpler CSS approach. He beat me to the punch so make sure to give him the accepted tick.

```js
//Add event listener
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){
  //Get tht toggleable rows
   document.querySelectorAll(".canToggle")
   //For each row
   .forEach(function(row){
      //Toggle the toggle class class
      row.classList.toggle("toggled");
   });  
})
```

```css
/*Hide the row by default , but no if it has the show class*/
.canToggle:not(.toggled) {display:none;}

/*If you want to have the row displayed initially and hide on click 
  replace the above line with the following (Courtesy of Stephens Answer)*/
/*.canToggle.toggled {display:none;}*/
```

```html
<h2>Table</h2>
<div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blank</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blank</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
              <tr class="canToggle">
                    <td>Show/Hide</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="canToggle">
                    <td>Show/Hide</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
   <button type="button" id="toggle">Show/Hide ▼</button>
```

Comment: Cool selector there Jon. I tend to try to make things obvious, so personally I think `.hideable.hidden {display:none;}` is the simpler css and is the only rule in my css that's necessary to make it work. But - Nice! - have my upvote.

Comment: @StephenP, you do have a point,  both work, and I really is a matter of preference. You have inspired me to make a slight improvement to make mine a little more generic, so if the initial state changes from hidden to shown, it's a one line CSS Change.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is always a good practice not to use the same ID more than once. So I have made a version which replaces your Html tag identifier from ID to using a class.

Added comments inline with the code for your understanding.In your case, since there are multiple items that you want to select, it is wise to put them in a list and iterate it one by one to apply the properties.

```js
function toggleTable()
{
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("hide"); // Since there are more than one item, lets park it into a list
  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) // iterating thru a list and applying properties to individual items
  {
     if( list[i].style.display =='none'){
       list[i].style.display = 'table-row'; // set to table-row instead of an empty string
     }else{
       list[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<h2>Table</h2>
<div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blank</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blank</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
              <tr class="hide" style="display:none;">
                    <td>Show/Hide</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
                <tr Class="hide" style="display:none;">
                    <td>Show/Hide</td>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
   <button type="button" onclick="toggleTable()">Show/Hide ▼</button>
```

Comment: "it is always a good practice not to use the same ID more than once" — it's not just good practice, any of your code using a duplicated ID will do unexpected things. It might act on the first place the ID appears, it might act on the last place the ID appears. It would be legitimate for a browser to do nothing at all because using duplicate IDs makes your page _invalid_.